# Bulma label doesn't fit input

Tags: html, css, bulma

I just want each label to take up only one line.

```
 <div class="container">
            <div class="columns">
                <div class="column"> 
                </div>
                <div class="column is-one-third">
                    <form>
                        <div class="field is-horizontal">
                            <div class="field-label is-normal">
                                <label class = "label" for="p1Name">PLAYER ONE</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field-body">
                                <input type="text" id="p1Name" class="input is-link" placeholder="TYPE PLAYER NAME">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field is-horizontal">
                            <div class="field-label is-normal">
                                <label class = "label" for="p2Name">PLAYER TWO</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field-body">
                                <input type="text" id="p2Name" class="input is-link" placeholder="TYPE PLAYER NAME">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is what's happening. The labels don't fit an input, They take up more than one line

[image: The labels don't fit an input, They take up more than one line]

So I try to add other containers to each input. It does work, but there is a lot of work we need to do more. Also, there is a big gap between labels and inputs.

```
<div class="column is-one-third">
                    <form>
                        <div class="field is-horizontal">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="columns">
                                    <div class="column is-4">
                                        <div class="field-label is-normal has-text-left">
                                            <label class = "label" for="p1Name">PLAYER ONE</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="column">
                                        <div class="field-body">
                                            <input type="text" id="p1Name" class="input is-link" placeholder="TYPE PLAYER NAME">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field is-horizontal">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="columns">
                                    <div class="column is-4">
                                        <div class="field-label is-normal has-text-left">
                                            <label class = "label" for="p2Name">PLAYER TWO</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="column">
                                        <div class="field-body">
                                            <input type="text" id="p2Name" class="input is-link" placeholder="TYPE PLAYER NAME">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                </div>
```

There is a big gap between labels and inputs

[image: There is a big gap between labels and inputs]

Is there any better approach?

Comment: are you following this example from *BULMA* [official docs](https://bulma.io/documentation/form/general/#horizontal-form)? If your `HTML` structure is similar to the docs then it should work.

Comment: @atiquratik Yes I did, I found that the problem is the space between "PLAYER" and "ONE". It seems like I can't use space between the words.